# Validation rule for 100 fields and editable only once by everyone but admin. Formula too long error

Tags: validation-rule

I have an object which has around 105 fields, but for the validation rule I need to use 100 fields. I need the fields to be editable if not null by all the profiles. However, the admin can edit any number of times.

For now, I have started with

```
OR(
AND(
ISCHANGED(field_1__c),
NOT ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(field_1__c))
),
AND(
ISCHANGED(field_2__c),
NOT ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(field_2__c))
), ...
```

I understand the other condition should be something like this

```
AND 
( 
 NOT(ISNEW()), 
 $Profile.Name <>'System Administrator'
)
```

Also while checking the syntax of the above rule(code snippet 1) , I am getting **Formula too long** error.
How do I write both of them efficiently together?

Answer (score 2):

Actually we can't do anything on Validation rule character limits. So you need to achieve this by splitting the number of fields validations check list as follows,

> Validation Rule 1 = 25 Fields with Administrator profile skip logic
>
> Validation Rule 2 = 25 Fields with Administrator profile skip logic
>
> Validation Rule 3 = 25 Fields with Administrator profile skip logic
>
> Validation Rule 4 = 25 Fields with Administrator profile skip logic

Sometimes if you want to achieve more then 100 fields..then you need to split the fields for No.of Validatation rule due to character limits of this SFDC Platform.

> But please remember no.of allowed Validation rules for an object is 500 Only.

Hope it helps.

Thanks.